# Is it possible to split a string that has spaces with the spread operator?

Tags: javascript

Instead of using `.split(" ")` to use the spread operator for this string: *The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog*.

Comment: You would have to modify `String.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` to achieve that which is not a good practice

Comment: `[..."STRING"]` gives you `["S","T","R","I","N","G"]`

Answer (score 8):

You could do that by overriding `String.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` like this but it's not considered a good practice to override JavaScript's native objects:

```js
String.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  const split = this.split(' ');
  for(const word of split) {
    yield word;
  }
}

const result = [...'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'];

console.log(result);
```

Shortest variant (thanks @georg):

```js
String.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  yield* this.split(' ');
}

const result = [...'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'];

console.log(result);
```

Other variant that simply returns the iterator from [`Array.prototype.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values):

```js
String.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function () {
  return this.split(' ').values();
}

const result = [...'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I consider myself fairly good at Javascript and Typescript, no issues with Promises, `async/await`, classes and all this stuff, but I haven't yet wrapped my head around what generators and `yield` are, or what their purpose is. I don't understand what exactly is going on in this code above (but since it's working I upvoted nonetheless :)

Comment: @Guerric P, I upvoted as well.
Man any reference how to got to know about javascript in this much depth?

Comment: Ahah thanks! According to me that's not the hardest thing to understand, just something we rarely use, I think you'll grasp it quickly if you play with it

Comment: @PawanSharma if you love JavaScript like I do then just read the documentation and experiment things by yourself, I don't know any better way to learn!

Comment: Yes I think they are pretty exhaustive while still explaining real use cases. The ECMAScript and WHATWG specifications are useful too when looking for specific information

Comment: simply `yield *this.split(' ')`

Comment: @JeremyThille You can achieve this without `yield` and stuff as well, you can check my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `String.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` but **NOT** recommended at all.

All I've done is created an array `words` by splitting over a single space and initialized a variable `count` to `0`.

Now I return a function `next` (which is what is called while iterating). The iteration stops when this function `next` returns an object with a property `done` which is set to `true`.

So, the code below will return `{done: false, value: "The"}` when `next` is called the first time and so one and finally at the very end calling `next` would return `{done: true}`, which would stop the execution.

```js
String.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  let words = this.split(" ");
  let count = 0
  return {
    next() {
      if (count < words.length) {
        return {done: false, value: words[count++]}
      }
      return {done: true}
    }
  }
}

console.log([..."The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"])
```

As suggested by GEORG in the comments you can simply return `this.split(' ').values()`.

`.values()` will return an iterator and Strings would simply use this iterator. But to understand how iterators work check the first example.

```js
String.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  return this.split(" ").values()
}

console.log([..."The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"])
```

Comment: simply `return this.split(' ').values()` ;)

Comment: COOL! `.values()` will return an iterator itself.